# How to store data locally in xamarin for user preferences

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

*In Android we use `SharedPreferences` to store the `UserPreferences` locally*

***I don't want to use Sqlite***

1. What do we need to use similar in MvvmCross platform xamarin
2. Which is the best way
3. Any simple samples to learn this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options to store user settings in cross platform projects.

- Use [Properties Dictionary](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/application-class/#Properties_Dictionary) available in Xamarin.
- You can also use [FileSystem](https://components.xamarin.com/view/pclstorage) plugin to store values in a file.
- [SimpleStorage](https://github.com/perpetual-mobile/SimpleStorage) is a lightweight library to store simple key-value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2020 [Xamarin.Essentials - Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android) is now one of the best ways if you dont want or need to use a database type solution like MySQL.

Have you check [SettingsPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin)?

Comment: There's an MvvmCross plugin based on this made by Cheesebaron, which is available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cheesebaron.MvxPlugins.Settings)